# Edit text not accepting value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have entered values in my text field, But the debugger shows null value.
The text id's are correct yet no value is being printed.
The log cat is showing null pointer exception. I have declared all the variables in the class.

The edit text string functions are declared in the method itself.

```
        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        et4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        et5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);

        set1 = et1.getText().toString();
        set2 = et2.getText().toString();
        set3 = et3.getText().toString();
        set4 = et4.getText().toString();
        set5 = et5.getText().toString();
        System.out.println("set1 ="+set1);
        System.out.println("set2 ="+set2);
```

All values given input are showing null and these are the few values that are being declared in the xml.

I need to know what mistake i am doing and how to rectify it.

i have initialized the values after setContent the data access happens in button on click listener... i didnt want to post the entire code.. –

Comment: it means that you are setting the wrong layout for your activity, since getText does not return null

Comment: Your Editext's are blank at this point. Hence you not getting anything.

Comment: Dont you think there should be some event, like onClick() event of the button,

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17808963/3330969).

You are directly accesssing the EditText's value after initializtion of EditText. You should accept the value on some event like onClick.

Let me Explain,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
      EditText editText; 

      @Override 
      public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
      { 
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           editText = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.firstEditText );

           String str = editText().getText().toString();
           // Here Str will be null blank all the time because EditText it self is blank.
       }
}
```

Now see this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
      EditText editText; 

      @Override 
      public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
      { 
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           editText = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.firstEditText );

           String str = editText().getText().toString();
           // Here Str will be null blank all the time, since you haven't input anything in your EditText
       }

       @Override 
       public void onClick ( View view )
       {
             // Assuming you have already put some text in edittext.
             String newStr = editText().getText().toString();
       }
}
```

Comment: i have initialized the values after setContent the data access happens in button on click listener...  i didnt want to post the entire code..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow some steps to find out your actual problem

1. check that you have set right layout in the setContentView.
2. before getting text from edit text set some text in it and then get text form the EditText view. Check that it still printing null.

   I think you have done some silly mistake because EditText.getText() never returns null.

Answer (score -1):

NullPoint exception is thrown because you are converting a **NULL** value to a string

```
et1.getText() is null and you are doing 
et1.getText().toString();
```

which is wrong.

Every `EditText` is initially `NULL` because it does not contain any value.

According to [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

> public Editable getText ()
>
> Added in API level 1
> Return the text the TextView is displaying.

Since the EditText has not been set any text hence its current value is null.

Comment: and which one is null ?

Comment: Everyone which is not initialized.

Comment: your statement `Every EditText is initially NULL because it does not contain any value.` does not make sense.

Comment: @blackbelt You already know what error is. its converting null to a String value.

Comment: you have two different objects. et1 and the return value of getText. Which one is null in your opinion?

Comment: et1.getText() is null. i.e. the return value of et1,et2,et3 etc

Comment: getText never returns null.